# Symfony - custom login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I need to implement one thing. In Symfony I have 2 firewalls (admin and whole web) - both using FOSUserBundle. Now I need to do a login for one simple section, which is a standalone part. I do not want to use User entity which I have for admin and web login, because I do not want to mix the users with the new section. So I created a standalone entity SectionUser and new firewall. Now I tried to log the user manually - with creating a new UsernamePasswordToken against the new firewall.

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "section", array());
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context'); // do it your way
$securityContext->setToken($token);
```

but I end up in infinite loop on /new-section/login. This is my security.yml and firewall settings:

```
section:
        pattern: ^/new-section(.*)
        form_login:
            login_path:     /new-section/login
            use_forward:    true
            check_path:     /new-section/login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /new-section/logout
        anonymous:    true
```

Do I need to implement anything else or my approach is wrong and I should use FOSUserBundle in any way? Thank you for pointing me a direction.

Is custom login provider a way? I am stuck here and do not know how to handle it.

Comment: I think you need implement your own `provider`.

Comment: Give us a look at your whole firewall setup (including the other areas) and your access-control setup.  Order of declarations is crucial.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZRaFAPtZ this is security.yml, /new-section is now /registrovana-sekce

Comment: And the most important thing for me is to have different entities and independent logins...

Comment: Anyone please? Is there any other way or do I need to search for how to implement custom login provider?